# Why is the letter f squished in the code tag

Tags: html, tags

I noticed that when the letter `f` acts strangely when it's in the `code` tag and followed by either its self or some other - but not all - characters.

For example:

```html
<code style="font-size: 200px;">fff</code>
```

Notice how the first two `f`s are squished together.

Another example:

```html
<code style="font-size: 100px;">Makefile</code>
<code style="font-size: 100px;">mono.txt</code>
```

Although the text in the `code` tag is supposed to be monospaced. The `f` and the `i` appear to take the space of a single character. And the string `mono.txt` seems to have one more character compared to the string `Makefile`. When in fact, they are the same length.

Is there any rationale behind this?

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot? It looks normal here in the code snippet with chrome

Comment: Just an observance - the letter `f` appears fine on Chrome for OS X.

Comment: are you using some odd proportional font?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I just looked at it in my phone, and it looks fine. It must be my system that uses some weird font. Sorry about the false alarm. I don't know if I should delete the post or keep it so that people can learn from my dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason, my browser was using a weird font called "Nimbus Mono Regular" for monospaced text. Which was the source of my misery. Thanks to the commenters for the help.